# Android ListView shows Old and New values using BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, scroll, baseadapter

I am using a custom BaseAdapter implementation for a Listview. Everything is fine until there are many items in the listview and the scrolling mechanism appears. (items exceed the listview height). When I now delete one item the listview refreshes and shows the right data for just milliseconds. After that it shows also the old values from time before deletion. But only for the items after the deleted entry. Every item above is ok. 
When I start scrolling now, everything is fine again?! Looks somehow as there is some caching problem or whatever?!

See the following files and pictures.

CustomBaseAdapter:

```
public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity context;
private List<Entry> objects;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;

private int textViewResourceId;

public CustomBaseAdapter(Activity context, int textViewResourceId,
                         List<Entry> objects) {
    this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
    this.objects = objects;
    this.context = context;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public void updateEntries(List<Entry> entries){
    ThreadPreconditions.checkOnMainThread();
    List<Entry> entryHelper = new ArrayList<>();
    entryHelper.addAll(entries);
    this.objects.clear();
    this.objects.addAll(entryHelper);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    EntryDataHolder holder;

    //TODO Views recycling implementieren. Ist derzeit auskommentiert aufgrund des Bug #203

    // If null we create row, if not we get the holder object of current row
    if (convertView == null) {
        // set the layout
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = li.inflate(textViewResourceId, null);
        holder = new EntryDataHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (EntryDataHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    // fill components with value
    Entry entry = objects.get(position);
    holder.tvCol1.setText(entry.getDateAsStringWithoutYear());
    holder.tvCol2.setText(entry.getDescription());
    holder.tvCol3.setText(entry.getAmountAsStringWithCurrency());

    // highlight text if item can be associated with a deposit
    if(entry instanceof Expense){
        if(((Expense)entry).getAssociatedDeposit() != null){
            ComponentUtil.setDepositAssociationColoring(holder.tvCol1);
            ComponentUtil.setDepositAssociationColoring(holder.tvCol2);
            ComponentUtil.setDepositAssociationColoring(holder.tvCol3);
        }else{
            ComponentUtil.setStandardColoring(holder.tvCol1);
            ComponentUtil.setStandardColoring(holder.tvCol2);
            ComponentUtil.setStandardColoring(holder.tvCol3);
        }
    }

    row.setTag(holder);
    return row;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public Entry getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
}

class EntryDataHolder {
    public TextView tvCol1;
    public TextView tvCol2;
    public TextView tvCol3;
    public EntryDataHolder(View base){
        tvCol1 = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.tvCol1);
        tvCol2 = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.tvCol2);
        tvCol3 = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.tvCol3);
    }
}
}
```

Activity class:

```
public class RevenueListActivity extends BaseActivity implements
    IDialogActionListener {

// view component references
private TextView tvHeader;
private TextView tvTotal;
private ListView lvData;
private CustomBaseAdapter adapter;
private List<Entry> tmpRevenues;

private AdView adView;

private MonthControl mControl;

private AbstractDialog entryDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_entry_list);

    // Add AdView
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llAdView);
    adView = AdViewManager.addAdToView(this, layout);

    initializeComponents();
    registerForContextMenu(lvData);
    loadIntentVariables();
    loadEntryList();
}

/**
 * Create the options menu for this activity
 */
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflator = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflator.inflate(R.menu.activity_entry_list, menu);

    // Readonly configuration
    MenuItem miAddEntry = menu.findItem(R.id.miAddEntry);
    if (mControl.getIsSaveable()) {
        miAddEntry.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        miAddEntry.setVisible(false);
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Create the context menu for the list
 */
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(android.view.ContextMenu menu, View v,
        android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    // Readonly configuration
    if (mControl.getIsSaveable()) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_entry_context_menu, menu);
    }
}

/**
 * Called if one of the Context Menu Item was clicked
 */
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // get selected item from list view
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();
    Object selectedObject = lvData.getAdapter().getItem(info.position);
    Entry selectedEntry = (Entry) selectedObject;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.miDeleteEntry:
        deleteSelectedEntry(selectedEntry);
        break;
    case R.id.miEditEntry:
        editSelectedEntry(selectedEntry);
        break;
    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Deletes the current selected entry from month control
 */
private void deleteSelectedEntry(Entry entryToDelete) {
    //mControl.deleteRevenue(entryToDelete);
    tmpRevenues.remove(entryToDelete);
    adapter.updateEntries(tmpRevenues);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * Opens the dialog for editing the selected entry
 * 
 * @param entryToEdit
 */
private void editSelectedEntry(Entry entryToEdit) {
    entryDialog.showDialog(entryToEdit);
}

/**
 * Called if one of the Option Menu Item was clicked
 */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // check which option menu item was clicked
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.miAddEntry:
        entryDialog.showDialog(null);
        break;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Called when dialog was committed with ok
 * 
 * @param event
 */
public void dialog_commitHandler(DialogEvent event) {
    // check which type of action was performed with the dialog
    if (event.getEventType().equals(DialogEvent.EDIT_ENTRY_EVENT)) {
        // Notify Month Control observers that the object has been modified.
        //mControl.changeOccured();
    } else if (event.getEventType().equals(DialogEvent.NEW_ENTRY_EVENT)) {
        //mControl.addRevenue(event.getEntry());
        tmpRevenues.add(event.getEntry());
    }
    adapter.updateEntries(tmpRevenues);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * Called when the dialog was canceled
 */
public void dialog_cancelHandler() {
    // Do nothing
}

/**
 * inject all needed components
 */
private void initializeComponents() {
    tvHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEntryListHeader);
    tvTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotal);
    lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvData);
}

/**
 * injects the right dialog after intent variables were loaded
 */
private void initializeDialog() {
    entryDialog = new RevenueDialog(this, R.layout.dialog_revenue);

    entryDialog.addEventListener(this);
}

/**
 * Loads extra values from intent and configures activity
 */
private void loadIntentVariables() {
    mControl = MonthControl.getInstance(null);
    // Readonly configuration
    tvHeader.setText(getText(R.string.tv_revenue_header)
            + (mControl.getIsSaveable() ? "" : " ("
            + getString(R.string.tv_archived_month) + ")"));

    // after intent were loaded we can init the associated dialog
    initializeDialog();
}

/**
 * Iterates through the entry list and adds them to a Adapter, which will be
 * used for the list view
 */
private void loadEntryList() {
    tmpRevenues = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    tmpRevenues.addAll(mControl.getRevenues());
    adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_item_layout_revenue, tmpRevenues);
    lvData.setAdapter(adapter);

    // make calculations
    calculateSum();
}

/**
 * calculates the sum of all entries
 */
private void calculateSum() {
    BigDecimal sum = BigDecimalFactory.createBigDecimal("0");

    for (Entry entry : tmpRevenues) {
        sum = sum.add(entry.getAmount());
    }
    tvTotal.setText(sum.toString() + " €");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (adView != null)
        adView.resume();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (adView != null)
        adView.resume();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (adView != null)
        adView.destroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Model class code:

```
public void deleteRevenue(Entry entry) {
    LogUtil.debug(MonthControl.class, TAG, "Deleting revenue...");

    revenues.remove(entry);

    notifyListener();
}

public List<Entry> getRevenues() {
    if (revenues == null) {
        revenues = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    }
    return revenues;
}
```

The list item Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:minHeight="40dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1.0" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCol1"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:lines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCol2"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:lines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCol3"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:lines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Befor deletion:

[image]

After deletion of 5th item:

[image]

After scrolling:

[image]

**UPDATE: Solution**
It is the layout. I just removed one liner_layout layer the listview was contained in. Now everything ist fine. 
This is the tested working layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llAdView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="75px"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- AdView inserted here at runtime -->
 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEntryListHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="@string/tv_date_header" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="@string/tv_description_header" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="@string/tv_amount_header" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvData"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_ui"
    android:divider="@color/dark_grey"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:padding="4dp" />

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:text="@string/tv_total" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTotal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2" />
 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post the code for this 
    mControl.deleteRevenue(entryToDelete); please?

Comment: @Want2bExpert I included those methods from the mControl model class

Comment: Try this. Create an helper method that remove entry from the revenue and returns new revenue.  Basically combine both deleteRevenue and getRevenu. So when you delete entry from revenue you call that helper method and then call notifyDataSetChange on adapter.

Comment: Alternatively, comment out this "revenues = new ArrayList<Entry>();" in getRevenues and just return revenues

Answer (score 0):

You are missing which is a must,

```
row.setTag(holder);// this is missing.
return row;
```

in your `getView` Method

and also, this is somewhat wrong according to your approach, So change to this and see,

```
   public void updateEntries(List<Entry> entries){
        ThreadPreconditions.checkOnMainThread();
        this.objects.clear();
        this.objects.addAll(entries);
    }
```

and also make sure that,

`mControl.getRevenues()` only returns values that are not deleted, if this method tend to return the same data as old data, then this is also wrong.

I think I got where the problem is,

remove the following method from your adapter.

```
public void updateEntries(List<Entry> entries){
    ThreadPreconditions.checkOnMainThread();
    List<Entry> entryHelper = new ArrayList<>();
    entryHelper.addAll(entries);
    this.objects.clear();
    this.objects.addAll(entryHelper);
}
```

This is what causing the problem.

and in this method,,

```
/**
 * Deletes the current selected entry from month control
 */
private void deleteSelectedEntry(Entry entryToDelete) {
    //mControl.deleteRevenue(entryToDelete);
    tmpRevenues.remove(entryToDelete);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

`adapter.updateEntries(tmpRevenues);` you will not call this method because when you remove the Entry earler, you are actually removing the items inside the adapter, because you are passing the same reference to the adapter.

But still, debug the application and see when you do the remove on the `tmpRevenues` that Entry is actually getting removed.

I am quoting your comment,

> if i update the "updateEntries" function as you showed i end up in
>   that scenario that my list is completely empty after deleting one
>   item. ?!? Maybe because of the refernce to the original list.

This solution will fix the above issue

Comment: Thank you for your fast response but the problem is still present :/ adding the row.setTag(holder) did not resolve the problem

Comment: if i update the "updateEntries" function as you showed i end up in that scenario that my list is completely empty after deleting one item. ?!? Maybe because of the refernce to the original list.

Comment: Good point. So I searched on the wrong side. I am currently not able to post any code, will do that when I am back home :) . Thank you very much!

Comment: I updated the code in my first post. Now I am only using a temporary list. So no external influence any more. But I still got the problem. Old data is never set (I debugged it) Somehow the Renderer is mixing up something what the scrollbar appears. Because in the getview method everything is fine. Never got any old values.?!

Comment: @MatthiasReisner can you check the new solution :).

Comment: There must be something with the layout or auto scrollbar. Nothing worked. I also tried to exchange the compley base adapter with the default array adapter and only using string objects. I got the same problem with those... :/

Comment: I updated my layout. Now it works. It was the layout ... :) Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be from 
 adapter.updateEntries(mControl.getRevenues());

It seems like mControl.getRevenues() returns the previous data.
Try commenting this line out and see.

BTW, you don't need to call adapter.updateEntries because notifyDataSetChange will do the adapter update.

Comment: I commented that part out but no change to my problem :/